# Spring Boot API returns infinite results upon GET request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have a basic Spring boot API with an object controller containing a GET mapping returning a single instance of an object. The object has no mapped relations and all fields are of primitive data types.
Yet, when calling the API, it will return one random instance from the database an infinite number of times.

The issue only occurs when the function getAll() has no parameters in the Controller and the Object Class.

1. The Object:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_CAR")
public class ObjCar implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "INDEX_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "INDEX_id_seq", sequenceName = "INDEX_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

public ArrayList<ObjCar> getAll(int uselessVariableCausingTroubleIfRemoved) {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Query query = DB.s.createQuery("from " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " where active = :active");
    query.setParameter("active", active);
    ArrayList<ObjCar> cots;
    cots = (ArrayList<ObjCar>) query.list();
    return cots;
}

// auto generated getters and setters
}
```

2. The Contoller that works

```java
@RestController
public class ObjCarController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/obj/ObjCar/get/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ArrayList<ObjCar > getAll() throws Exception {
        return new ObjCar().getAll(135);
    }

}
```

2. The Contoller that does not work

```java
@RestController
public class ObjCarController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/obj/ObjCar/get/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ArrayList<ObjCar > getAll() throws Exception {
        return new ObjCar().getAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: okay this is entity `ObjCar` and repository layer should be different one

Comment: What is the actual query that is getting fired? Can you share that as well?